# Getting problem with: docker-compose up -d

Tags: docker-compose

I am trying to create a container using **docker-compose up -d** but it shows **command not found**. I even switch the owner to jenkins then too its showing the same. Working through Oracle virtual box and ssh with mobaxterm. Help me out!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uJai.jpg)

Comment: That means that either the `docker-compose` is not installed, or not in your path.

Comment: @nikoksr can you let me know how to setup the path. I used below command to install

Comment: @nikoksr can you let me know how to setup the path. I used below command to install:
curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.29.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$ (uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose


chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose


but it is showing :
[root@localhost jenkins]# docker-compose --version
bash: docker-compose: command not found

but if i am doing this... it showing

[jenkins@localhost ~]$ docker compose version
Docker Compose version v2.3.3

Didn't able to get it..whats wrong?

Comment: Well, for one you could start with `/usr/local/bin/docker-compose -h`. This ignores your path and uses the binary you installed directly. You can use this to verify that your installation worked in the first place.

Comment: Sorry for the split answers.. however, the fact that the `docker compose` command seems to be working in constrast to the `docker-compose` binary indicates that you at least have a working `docker` installation. I'm not entirely sure on this, but I think that these days you don't even need to explicitly install the `docker-compose` binary anymore. `docker compose` is a drop-in replacement for it and since it seems to be working, I'd go with this one. You can read [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/#compose-v2-and-the-new-docker-compose-command) for more info on this.